# Twig delegate part of template to a symfony 3 service

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to delegate the rendering of part of my template to a service into my controller.

Something like this

Index.html.twig

```
<div>
  {% include 'service.html.twig' %}
</div>
<div>
  Rest of my template
</div>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

// some previous operations
$service->display();
// some next operations
return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
  'value'=> $myvalue
  //more
]);
```

Service.php

```
<?php
class service
{

  private $templating;

  public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $templating)
  {
    $this->templating = $templating;
  }
  function display()
  {
    $this->templating->render('service.html.twig', [
      'mytest' => 'hello include'
    ]);

  }
}
```

Service.html.twig

```
TEST var {{mytest}}
```

How can achieve that with twig ?

Comment: Guessing you are looking for [this](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html)?

Comment: there are lots of ways to achieve this. you could expose the service to twig via a twig extension (that would probably be my approach), otherwise as DarkBee suggested, embedding a controller for this is also feasible.

Comment: @DarkBee I knew this kind of approach, but I want delegate this piece of work to a service

Comment: @jakumi is it possible to you to provide me some example ? I know how declare a Twig extension but I'm not sure to understand how it could be an anwser to my purpose

Comment: @akio something along the lines of  what Florian Hermann answered. however, there really should be no need to "include" the service into twig, when it's functions would be enough ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve your goal with a Twig extension.

Create your extension and inject your service via the constructor

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Your\Service;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /** @var Service*/
    private $service;

    public function __construct(Service $service)
    {
        $this->service= $service;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('your_function_name', [$this->service, 'display'], ['is_safe' => ['html']),
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see, the getFunctions method allows you to declare custom twig functions. This method return an array of TwigFunction.
The constructor of the TwigFunction class expects the following arguments:

- The function name that you will use in your templates.
- A callable that will be executed when you call the function (here it's a direct call to your service)
- The third one is an optional array of options. In your case, you have to use it in order to allow your function to return non escaped html.

You can now in your template call the function "your_function_name":

```
<div>
  {{ your_function_name() }}
</div>
<div>
  Rest of my template
</div>
```

Comment: thanks to you guys it works like a charm for my need